# SQL grouping query for range

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a bit new to SQL and I am stuck with the grouping part. I have a table with universities and I want to group them. The table something looks like below,

```
Universities                  Ranking
University of Arizona          38
Havard University              6
RMIT                           213
University of Sheffield        106
York University                111
Korea University               63
University of Melbourne        59
University of Waterloo         78
```

I want to make a new table using this above table. My new table should look like the below,

```
 Ranking                  No of Universities
 1-50                           x
 51-99                          x
 100-149                        x
 so on
```

How can I do the grouping in this case? Especially with the range in the first column.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: are you on SQL Server or MySQL? Also, this looks like homework. What have you tried already? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: Case, Sum, Count... That's all I'm going to say.

Comment: I am using oracle toad and I believe it is on SQL server. This is a simple query which I am trying to figure out myself. This is not a homework or something.

Comment: "*I am using Oracle I believe it is on SQL Server*" makes no sense. Oracle and SQL Server are two very different database products.

Comment: You certainly want ranges of equal length. Hence 1-50, 51-**100**, **101-150**, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN Ranking >= 1 AND Ranking <= 50 THEN '1-50'
            WHEN Ranking >= 51 AND Ranking <= 100 THEN '51-100'
        END AS Range
,       COUNT(1) AS Number
FROM    Your_Table
GROUP BY CASE
            WHEN Ranking >= 1 AND Ranking <= 50 THEN '1-50'
            WHEN Ranking >= 51 AND Ranking <= 100 THEN '51-100'
        END
```

Comment: you mean And Ranking <= 50?

Comment: @Ik1904p  There was a typo, which I've now corrected. Did you mean that? My ranges are a bit different from what you mentioned, but this is the general idea

Answer (score 1):

I setup a test table with your data.

```
    CREATE TABLE #TmpUni (
     Uni varchar(100)
    ,Ranking smallint );

INSERT INTO #TmpUni
SELECT 'University of Arizona', 38
INSERT INTO #TmpUni
SELECT 'Havard University', 6
INSERT INTO #TmpUni
SELECT 'RMIT', 100
INSERT INTO #TmpUni
SELECT 'University of Sheffield', 106
INSERT INTO #TmpUni
SELECT 'York University', 111
INSERT INTO #TmpUni
SELECT 'Korea University', 63
INSERT INTO #TmpUni
SELECT 'University of Melbourne', 59
INSERT INTO #TmpUni
SELECT 'University of Waterloo', 78;

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
         Ranking = CASE WHEN Ranking BETWEEN 1 AND 50 THEN '1-50'
                        WHEN Ranking BETWEEN 51 AND 99 THEN '51-99'
                        WHEN Ranking BETWEEN 100 AND 150 THEN '100 - 150'
                   END
        ,Uni
    FROM #TmpUni )

SELECT DISTINCT
     Ranking
    ,COUNT (Uni) OVER (PARTITION BY Ranking) AS NumberOfUniversities 
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic list of universities you can query as below:

```
;with cte as ( --Tally table to get list of numbers 
    select top (select (max(ranking)/50)+1 from youruniversity) rowN = (row_number() over (order by (select null)) *50)-50 from master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
), cte2 as (  --We can avoid this cte by adding and subtracting in first cte, you can do that
    select concat(RowN+1 , '-', lead(rown,1,rown+50) over (order by RowN)) as [Range], RowN+1 as Startid, lead(rown,1,rown+50) over (order by RowN) as EndId 
    from cte
)  --Final query just by group by 
select [Range] as  [Ranking], count(distinct Universtities) as [No Of Universities] 
from cte2 cross join youruniversity
where ranking > startid and  ranking <= endid
group by [range]
```

Output as below:

```
+---------+--------------------+
| Ranking | No Of Universities |
+---------+--------------------+
| 1-50    |                  2 |
| 101-150 |                  2 |
| 201-250 |                  1 |
| 251-300 |                  1 |
| 51-100  |                  3 |
+---------+--------------------+
```

For input as below:

```
create table youruniversity (Universtities varchar(50), Ranking int)

insert into youruniversity (Universtities, Ranking) values
 ('University of Arizona  ',        38  )
,('Havard University      ',        6   )
,('RMIT                   ',        213 )
,('University of Sheffield',        106 )
,('York University        ',        111 )
,('Korea University       ',        63  )
,('University of Melbourne',        59  )
,('University of Waterloo ',        78  )
,('Madurai Kamaraj University',     280 ) --added for testing
```

Answer (score 0):

You want groups of ranges of 50 numbers, so use some math to get the groups:

```
select
  trunc((ranking - 1) / 50) * 50 + 1 as ranking_from,
  trunc((ranking - 1) / 50) * 50 + 50 as ranking_till,
  count(*) as no_of_universities
from mytable
group by trunc((ranking - 1) / 50)
order by trunc((ranking - 1) / 50);
```